# Kotlin Native cinterop framework with dependency on CoreLocation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm trying to add a cinterop for a framework.

My def file looks like

```
language = Objective-C
modules = ModuleName
linkerOpts = -framework ModuleName
```

It is failing with error message cannot find protocol declaration for `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

I tried added `-framework CoreLocation` as a compiler option, but it still doesn't find it.

How do you create a cinterop for a framework that depends on `CoreLocation`?

I noticed the header file has

```
@class CLLocationManager;
@class CLLocation;
@class CLHeading;
```

But no foreword declaration of CLLocationManagerDelegate, but I don't know enough about Swift and Objective-C to tell if that is a broken header file or not.

I tried manually adding the forward declaration but got the same error message.

I also removed all the references to CoreLocation from the header file and it gets to another part where it depends on a class from another framework.  That code is needed and cannot be removed.

The header file includes imports for this framework and CoreLocation, but it still cannot find the symbols.  There's no errors about the import.

Tried adding the -framework options as compiler options, but it still cannot find the symbols.  There are -F options for the framework search paths.

```
        val architecturePath = when(targetName) {
            "iosX64" -> "ios-x86_64-simulator"
            "iosArm64" -> "ios-arm64"
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown architecture, $targetName")
        }
        val mapboxCoreMaps = File(projectDir, "libs/MapboxCoreMaps.xcframework/$architecturePath").absolutePath
        val mapboxMaps = File(projectDir, "libs/MapboxMaps.xcframework/$architecturePath").absolutePath
        compilations {
            @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
            val main by getting {
                cinterops {
                    val mapbox by creating {
                        defFile = File("$projectDir/libs/mapbox.def")
                        packageName("com.mapbox")
                        compilerOpts("-F$mapboxCoreMaps", "-F$mapboxMaps", "-framework", "MapboxCoreMaps")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Mapbox.def

```
language = Objective-C
modules = MapboxMaps
linkerOpts = -framework MapboxCoreMaps -framework MapboxMaps
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add depends section to the .def file. For example, see how it is done [at the Kotlin/Native repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/platformLibs/src/platform/ios/CoreData.def), where the CoreData framework is defined as a platform library. I would say it should look somehow like

```
depends =CoreLocation
language = Objective-C
modules = MapboxMaps

compilerOpts = -framework MapboxCoreMaps -framework MapboxMaps
linkerOpts = -framework MapboxCoreMaps -framework MapboxMaps
```

Comment: Hi, @MichaelKrussel! That's not good. Does the `depends` section change anything?

Comment: No, I still get the warning about unable to find `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

Comment: I created my own framework that uses `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and get similar error, but I've created cinterop definitions before that include `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Only difference is those were Objective-C frameworks and these are Swift frameworks with Objective-C bindings.

Comment: Well, could you please consider filing an issue at kotl.in/issue with a project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'll create one, just need to create a small example of the problem.